# Prove that p(x) cannot have more than m zeros , where $p(x)$ is a polynominal of degree m and $p(x) ∈ \mathbb{K} [x]$ and $\mathbb{K}$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question is as stated in the title: 
Prove that p(x) cannot have more than m zeros $p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is a polynominal of degree m and $p(x) ∈ \mathbb{K} [x]$ and $\mathbb{K}$ is a field . (where the zeros are counted with multiplcities)

I am also given the hint :  Use the fact that $\mathbb{K} [x]$ is a factorial ring

Comment: Note that if $\alpha$ is a root for $p(x)$, then $(x - \alpha) \mid p(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Any root of a polynomial is intricately linked to a linear factor, and polynomials have degrees.